# IIS and MS Exchange Realtime Log

Tags: iis, logging, real-time, exchange-server

How can I get IIS and MS Exchange logs in realtime? Is there a similar way like viewing EventLog by MS Visual C++ functions, classes (ex. NotifyChangeEventLog)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IIS 7.5 supports Real-Time Logging:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-real-time-logging